# findstr is not saving new file as expected

Tags: windows, command-line, findstr

I have used this command, to create a new file after searching for a query using findstr

```
find /c "Total record count" Movements_*.csv.old   && ( findstr /v /c:"Total record count" Movements_*.csv.old >> result.csv)
```

This is saving the expected results in result.csv, but Movements_20150317 is added before and after the data like this:

```
"Movements_20150317.csv.old:AGREEMENT,CURRENCY,MARGIN TYPE,AGREEMENT BRANCH NAME,AGREEMENT BRANCH CIS CODE,NOTIONAL LABEL,IDMovements_20150317.csv.old:"
```

Please suggest, how can this be removed?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /c "Total record count" Movements_*.csv.old   && ( for %a in (Movements_*.csv.old) do @findstr /v /c:"Total record count" "%~a" )>result.csv
```

Comment: Hi @endoro I am getting the following error on using the above command:

The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~a" )>result.csv


For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: @ShikhaPrasad if you use the command in a batch script, you must replace every single percent `%` with it's double `%%` .